# Specific changes to LaTeX section titles

Tags: latex

I need my whole document to be in 12pt font. My problem with that is related to the chapter, section, subsections titles. I'd like to make any of those titles bold only and 12pt. I think I can use titlesec but I'm not sure how to.

I would like something like this:

> **CHAPTER NAME** 
> **1.1 Section** 
> Section text

Here is what I have in LaTeX:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{report} % better for longer documents
    \usepackage{graphicx} % required for inserting images
    \usepackage{geometry} % required for changing margins
    \usepackage{setspace} % for spacing of the lines
    \usepackage{lipsum} % for fake text
    
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    
    \makeatletter
    \patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\LARGE}{\Large}{}{}
    \makeatother
    
    
    \usepackage{titlesec} % remove chapter name
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display] 
      {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
    
    
    \usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} %for chemistry formulas
    
    \usepackage{booktabs} % for tables
    
    \usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption} % for having table captions on top
    
    \usepackage{enumerate} %for initial page counts
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{2} % for numbering each section
    
    \usepackage{natbib} % for citations
    \setcitestyle{plainnat,open={(},close={)}} %Citation-related commands
    
    \usepackage{fontspec} % changing font
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman} % choosing font
    
    % for indenting the first line
    \usepackage{indentfirst}
    
    %for margins
    \newgeometry{
    top = 1in,
    bottom = 1in,
    outer = 1in,
    inner = 1in
        }
    
    \doublespacing
    
    \begin{document}
    
   
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begingroup
    \begin{center}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    my awesome title \\
    Submitted in partial fulfillment \\
    of the requirements for the degree of \\
    super smart person \\ 
    in cool science stuff \\
    at \\
    school of cool science stuff \\
    nice university \\
    month 2024
    } \end{center}
    \endgroup
    \vspace*{\fill}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/711783/36296

Answer (score 0):

The `sectsty` package offers a convenient way change the font of section titles:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont\scshape\bfseries}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\chapter{title}
\section{title}
test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. How do I do that and at the same time change it bold and/or all CAPS?